# IE11 meta element Breaks SVG

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, internet-explorer-11

I've embedded an SVG files data directly into my html. It shows in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE11 it doesn't show at all.  The pastebin link to the SVG is http://pastebin.com/eZpLXFfD

I've tried adding a META TAG but to no avail. At first I thought it might be a IE Compatibility view issue, but toggling that feature did not work either.

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">`

Any help?  What else Information Can I provide to help answer this question

Comment: *How* are you displaying this in your HTML document?

Comment: I've got the SVG code saved in a php file, and then using
`<?php require('inc/svg-map.php');?>`
To call in the php file. It's not contained in any element though.  The actual SVG php file is in the pastebin shown

Comment: The only way that works to me is setting the width and height of svg image.

Comment: The Pastebin is no longer available. Please create a [mcve] and add it directly to your post without relying on links.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It sounds as though you're not in a modern document mode. Internet Explorer 11 shows the SVG just fine when you're in Standards Mode. Make sure that if you have an `x-ua-compatible` meta tag, you have it set to Edge, rather than an earlier mode.

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

You can determine your document mode by opening up your F12 Developer Tools and checking either the document mode dropdown (seen at top-right, currently "Edge") or the emulation tab:

[image]

If you do not have an `x-ua-compatible` meta tag (or header), be sure to use a doctype that will put the document into Standards mode, such as `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same problem with 3 of 4 inline svgs I was using, and they only disappeared (in one case, partially) on IE11.

I had `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">` on the page.

In the end, the problem was extra clipping paths on the svg file. I opened the files on Illustrator, removed the clipping path (normally at the bottom of the layers) and now they're all working.

Comment: can you kindly provide an example of such path? Struggling with a similar issue at the moment.

Comment: Hi @montrealist ! Unfortunately I don't have an Illustrator to help you by reproducing the problem. If you have illustrator, it should be easy to check if an svg has a 'clipping path'. Let's say you have an svg icon, open it on Illustrator, hit 'a' to use the 'direct selection tool' and try to select one of the corners of the 'artboard'. If you can select it and it isn't part of the svg/icon, it's probably a clipping path. Try hitting delete a couple of times to delete it. I really don't remember how clipping paths were showing on the svg code but I hope this helps! Are you from montreal city?

Comment: Yes sir, sitting right here in an office on the Plateau. :) I don't have Illustrator, just playing with the code directly. Hope I won't have to download the whole thing for this bug...

Comment: Nice! Canal Lachine / Marché Atwater here =)
Wish I had Illustrator to see what clipping paths become on svg code =/
In your position, I'd try to remove chunks from the svg code and test on IE, but you probably tried that already, right?

Comment: Illustrator trick worked for me, though not sure it had to do any thing with clipping, illustrator just changed the "d" attribute value of my svg shape and added few more attributes in "svg" tag.

Comment: Thank you! I actually solved this by simply opening the file referencing the SVG in a text editor and removing the clipping path, along with the reference in the `path` element.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! The page was rendering using IE8 mode... had

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">`

in the header... changed it to

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">`

9 and it worked!

Comment: Do you have a reason to limiting yourself to the IE 9 document mode?

Comment: He's an absolute #madlad

Answer (score 2):

After trying the other suggestions to no avail I discovered that this issue was related to styling for me. I don't know a lot about the why but I found that my SVGs were not visible because they were not holding their place in the DOM.

In essence, the containers around my SVGs were at width: 0 and overflow: hidden.

I fixed this by setting a width on the containers but it is possible that there is a more direct solution to that particular issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue and resolved it by removing the width styling I had used on the SVG:

```
.svg-div img {
    width: 200px; /* removed this */
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate style attributes on each element.

```
style="opacity:0.8"
```

This certainly does not display on Firefox for me because of this error. If it displays on Chrome, best raise a Chrome bug.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Robert... I just removed the duplicate style tags and still no go... :/

Answer (score -1):

Check if the Browser is IE -

```
  $ua = htmlentities($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  if (preg_match('~MSIE|Internet Explorer~i', $ua) || (strpos($ua, 'Trident/7.0') !== false && strpos($ua, 'rv:11.0') !== false)) {
    // do stuff for IE Here
  }
```