# SVG translate transform in javascript not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, svg, transform

The following code doesn't work in IE 11 (Chrome works fine)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {document.getElementById("abc").style.transform = "translate(100px,100px)";};
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>   
        <svg width="200" height="200">
            <g id="abc">
                <polygon points="14,7 0,14 0,0"></polygon>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Chk this.. Might help..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494296/svg-not-showing-in-ie11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IE you need to set transform as an attribute rather than as a CSS style.

Note that for an attribute, units are not allowed.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {document.getElementById("abc").setAttribute("transform", "translate(100, 100)")};
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>   
        <svg width="200" height="200">
            <g id="abc">
                <polygon points="14,7 0,14 0,0"></polygon>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
```