# How can I get smooth markers (SVG icons) on Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I create a marker to place on a Google map:

```
var compMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 33, lng: -118}
    map: map,
    label: {
        text: "10",
        color: "white",
        fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        scale: 15,
        fillColor: "#4E90D9",
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 1
    }
});
```

This is the result:

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

As you can see the circle is pretty choppy looking.  Is there a way to create a high quality circle?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option would be to use a custom SVG icon.

```
icon: {
  url:'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent ('<svg viewBox="0 0 220 220" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="110" cy="110" r="100" stroke="black" fill="#4E90D9" fill-opacity="1.0" stroke-width="10" /></svg>'),
  size: new google.maps.Size(200,200),
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32,32),
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(16,16),
  labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16,16)
},
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/LL33qqcv/)

[image: screenshot of result]

Related questions dealing with issues in IE11:

- [How to use SVG markers in Google Maps API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413766/how-to-use-svg-markers-in-google-maps-api-v3)
- [SVG translate transform in javascript not working in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109349/svg-translate-transform-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie-11)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(53.3163803, -6.2676661),
    myOptions = {
      zoom: 15,
      center: pointA
    },
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
    markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointA,
      title: "SVG icon",
      label: {
        text: "10",
        color: "white"
      },
      icon: {
         url:'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent('<svg viewBox="0 0 220 220" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="110" cy="110" r="100" stroke="black" fill="#4E90D9" fill-opacity="1.0" stroke-width="10" /></svg>'),
        size: new google.maps.Size(200, 200),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 16),
        labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(16, 16)
      },
      map: map
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id='map-canvas'></div>
```