# AngularJS and IE issue

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code that shows the user avatar:

```
<div class="dashboard_image" style="background-image:url({{(user.avatar!=null)?user.avatar:'/img/general_user.svg'}})" style="width:200px;height:200px"></div>
```

If user do not have any image, **user.avatar** comes null.

In Chrome works fine but not in IE 11. What's wrong?

Comment: Have u checked that if your html document is properly rendered (whether the style of that element holds the right value)?After reading your comments, I doubt your issue may be not at the angular side but have something to do with the [SVG display problem in IE 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494296/svg-not-showing-in-ie11).

Comment: @MMhunter I thought so but in header, the SVG is shown perfectly. That's the strange thing!

Answer (score 3):

Try using ng-style, which exists for this purpose.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

```
<div
    class="dashboard_image"
    style="width:200px;height:200px"

    ng-style="{
        backgroundImage: 'url(' + (user.avatar!=null ? user.avatar : '/img/general_user.svg') + ')'
    }">
</div>
```

(not tested)

Comment: It arises an error: angular.js:13550 Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$parse/syntax?p0=%2F&p1=not%20a%20primary…_user.svg%20%2B%20')'%20%7D&p4=%2Fimg%2Fgeneral_user.svg%20%2B%20')'%20%7D

Comment: Lose the `{{` and `}}` curly braces from the ng-style expression: `{
        backgroundImage: 'url(' + (user.avatar!=null) ? user.avatar : '/img/general_user.svg)'
    }`

Comment: Now error free but do not show the image in neither case.

Comment: I changed it a little: ng-style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + (user.avatar!=null ? user.avatar : '/img/general_user.svg') + ')' }". Now it works.

Comment: I altered it even further. Like I said - I did not test it and obviously it was a mistake :))

Comment: @ZdenekHatak Your last update works but the problem is that in case there is no avatar, the defult image is not shown in IE11. In Chrome works fine.

Comment: What if you loose the "!=null" part and leave only "user.avatar" checking?

Comment: Alternatively can you do the checking in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
<div class="dashboard_image" ng-style="{'background-image': user.avatar!=null ? 'url(user.avatar)' : 'url(/img/general_user.svg)'" style="width:200px;height:200px"></div>
```

Comment: The main issue still remains. In case there is no avatar, the default image is not shown in IE11, but in Chrome yes.