# SVG Path animated Text does not render in IE11

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg

ladies and gentlemen.

```js
(function() {
  var charParts, i, j, len, part, partElem, resize;

  charParts = ["d-1", "d-2", "e-1", "e-2", "s-1", "i-1", "i-2", "g-1", "g-2", "n-1", "n-2"];

  partElem = $("path");

  for (j = 0, len = charParts.length; j < len; j++) {
    part = charParts[j];
    $("svg").append(partElem.clone().attr("class", part));
  }

  i = setInterval(function() {
    return $("div").toggleClass("text");
  }, 7000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    return $("div").toggleClass("text");
  }, 100);

  $("div").click(function() {
    clearInterval(i);
    return $("div").toggleClass("text");
  });

  resize = function() {
    return $("body").css({
      "margin-top": ~~((window.innerHeight - 400) / 2) + "px"
    });
  };

  $(window).resize(resize);

  resize();

  //get the line lengths
//$("path").each (i) -> console.log @getTotalLength()

}).call(this);
```

```css
body,
html,
div {
  background: #5677fc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
svg {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
path {
  fill: none;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95), stroke-dasharray 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  -moz-transition: stroke-dashoffset 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95), stroke-dasharray 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  -o-transition: stroke-dashoffset 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95), stroke-dasharray 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  -ms-transition: stroke-dashoffset 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95), stroke-dasharray 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95), stroke-dasharray 5.5s cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke: #f5f6f7;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  stroke-dasharray: 0px 1180px;
}
.text path.d-1 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -149px;
  stroke-dasharray: 22px 1180px;
}
.text path.d-2 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -201.3px;
  stroke-dasharray: 49px 1180px;
}
.text path.e-1 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -377.5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 14px 1180px;
}
.text path.e-2 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -431.2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 43px 1180px;
}
.text path.s-1 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -526px;
  stroke-dasharray: 37px 1180px;
}
.text path.i-1 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -631px;
  stroke-dasharray: 0.1px 1180px;
}
.text path.i-2 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -637.5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 16px 1180px;
}
.text path.g-1 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -732.5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 15px 1180px;
}
.text path.g-2 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -812px;
  stroke-dasharray: 69px 1180px;
}
.text path.n-1 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -941px;
  stroke-dasharray: 17px 1180px;
}
.text path.n-2 {
  stroke-dashoffset: -1013px;
  stroke-dasharray: 33.5px 1180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 300 200">
    <path class="motion" d="
      M  0,  0
      C  0,  0  99,  1  99, 89
      L 99,111
      C 99,130  75,112  99,112
      C103,112 100,112 106,112
      C121,112 121, 89 105, 89
      C 88, 89 102, 89  99, 89
      C  0, 89  80,103 123,103
      C128,103 135,103 136,103
      C155,103 137,140 137,103
      C137, 92 123, 93 123,103
      C123,115 135,113 137,110
      C152, 86 103, 87 143,110
      C152,116 157,106 147,103
      C140,102 143, 93 152, 96
      C206,118 159.5,50 159,89
      L159,112
      C159,180 117, 93 168,118
      C176,122 180,116 180,115
      C183,107 169,101 168, 90
      C167, 77 180, 67 180, 95
      L180,103
      C180,115 166,115 166,103
      C166, 92 180, 94 180,102
      C180,180 188,125 188,112
      C188,110 188,100 188, 96
      C188, 91 189, 80 194, 91
      C200,101 186,134 188,106
      C189, 93 201, 93 201,100
      C201,105 201,105 201,112
      C201,130 220,160 300, 80
    "></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I found beautiful SVG animation recently.
It works perfect in all the major browsers except IE 11 and that's the problem.
I'm check twice support table for CSS and HTML and everything seems to be fine.
Is IE11 not animating stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset?Is there a polyfill for this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494296/ie11-meta-element-breaks-svg

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, IE does not support SVG + CSS Animation, while Microsoft Edge does. Additionally, IE and Edge both don't support SVG + SMIL animation.

One possible solution is to use SVG + SMIL with [FakeSmile library](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/), or you can convert it to PNG Sequence / GIF with libraries like [Loading.io's SMILTool Library](https://github.com/loadingio/smil-to-gif), which also supports animation with SVG + CSS Animation.

Since SVG provide much better quality than GIF, you can consider serving animation in both format (SVG and GIF), depending on the client's browser. This could be easily done by configuring your web server.

Comment: I found the way to solve the problem with requestAnimationFrame