# SVG in IE 11 + Angular doesn't have a content type

Tags: angular, svg

I'm building an Anguar 8 application, and it uses a library (a library created by a team within my company) which contains an SVG for a background image style.

For development purposes on my computer, Chrome and IE 11 (IE version 11.805.17763.0IS) load the SVG just fine. However, the  application is being deployed to a Citrix server with IE 11 version 11.0.9600.19180CO. Locally on my computer, the file content type in the network properties console tab shows correctly as image/svg+xml. However on the Citrix server's IE 11, the content type is empty and the end result is that the SVG does not show.

the full CSS:

```
.date-facade > button {
  background: transparent url('../img/ico-calendar-blue.svg') no-repeat scroll 50% 50%;
  background-size: 1.2rem 1.2rem;
  border-color: #CED3D9;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.29em;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.29em;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.2rem;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.2rem;
  border-width: 0 0 0 .1em;
  border-width: 0 0 0 .08rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 2.68em;
  height: 2.2rem;
  margin-left: 0.25em;
  margin-left: 0.15rem;
  padding: 0;
  width: 2.9em;
  width: 2.2rem;
}
```

(I don't know why the library specifies some of these attributes in both rem and em, that's just how the library is.)

The svg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 19 19" enable-background="new 0 0 19 19" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#1893D1" d="M17.7,2h-0.9V1.7C16.8,0.7,16,0,15.1,0h-0.9c-0.9,0-1.7,0.7-1.7,1.7V2h-0.8V1.7C11.7,0.7,10.9,0,10,0H9
    C8.1,0,7.3,0.7,7.3,1.7V2H6.6V1.7C6.6,0.7,5.8,0,4.9,0H3.9C3,0,2.2,0.7,2.2,1.7V2H1.3C0.6,2,0,2.5,0,3.2v14.5C0,18.4,0.6,19,1.3,19
    h16.4c0.7,0,1.3-0.6,1.3-1.2V3.2C19,2.5,18.4,2,17.7,2z M17,6v3h-3V6H17z M6,10h3v3H6V10z M5,13H2v-3h3V13z M9,14v3H6v-3H9z M10,14
    h3v3h-3V14z M10,10h3v3h-3V10z M14,10h3v3h-3V10z M13.4,1.7c0-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.8-0.8H15c0.4,0,0.8,0.4,0.8,0.8v2.5
    C15.9,4.6,15.5,5,15,5h-0.9c-0.4,0-0.8-0.4-0.8-0.8V1.7z M13,6v3h-3V6H13z M8.2,1.7c0-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.8-0.8h0.9
    c0.4,0,0.8,0.4,0.8,0.8v2.5c0,0.4-0.4,0.8-0.8,0.8H9.1C8.6,5,8.2,4.6,8.2,4.2V1.7z M9,6v3H6V6H9z M3.1,1.7c0-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.8-0.8
    h0.9c0.4,0,0.8,0.4,0.8,0.8v2.5C5.6,4.6,5.3,5,4.8,5H4C3.5,5,3.1,4.6,3.1,4.2V1.7z M5,6v3H2V6H5z M2,14h3v3H2V14z M14,17v-3h3v3H14z
    "/>
</svg>
```

Is there something wrong with the library's SVG, or with Angular + SVG? I've been scouring google and stack overflow for posts regarding SVG not having a content type, but haven't come up with anything. I suspect that the SVG isn't showing because the content type isn't specified, but I don't know why it's not specified or how to fix it. When I copy the file path and open the image in a separate tab, the XML shows instead of an SVG image.

Of note is that the library has a demo site, and when I load the demo site in the Citrix IE the SVG loads fine.

Comment: This is usually a sign that there is an actual issue with the server setup. It simply doesn’t know (or even allow) files with an svg extension.

Comment: @MikeOne even though the demo site loads fine?

Comment: I think you should note what you have tried, so we don't have to guess or suggest things you've already done.

Comment: For example: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494296/ie11-meta-element-breaks-svg

Comment: @shadowfox476 the problem is that there's no content type. I did try playing with css in the browser, unchecking heights and widths and other attributes. 

<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"> This is already on the angular app's index.html

Comment: Is the content being served from localhost when it isn't working? I know I've run into an issue recently where group policy was preventing svgs from loading in IE11.

Comment: No, it's being served from the Citrix server. Localhost works on my own computer, and running the app through tomcat in my local machine also works. What I'm baffled at is that if this was a server issue, how can the demo site work just fine?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what web server the angular application is deployed to.

If IE11 has issues displaying SVG in Citrix, then chrome, firefox and other browsers shouldn't also be able to render the SVG.

If your web server is IIS, then you can add mimeType in IIS Console.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Would this be something a system administrator would do? I don't have access to the server side of things. I'm able to deploy to the server, but that's about it.

Comment: If you know who deploys your angular application, you can ask them for help.